# PostgreSQL configuration issue in sqlDeveloper

Tags: postgresql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to add postgreSQL in SQL developer 3.2.

Have read the steps from many reference sites and have even added multiple third party jars for other DB in past.

I am downloading jar from https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html

my system is working with jdk 1.7

However, after adding the postgresql jar, I am unable to see postgre tab in new connection dialogue box.

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded the sql developer version to 4.0.1 and that resolved the issue.

Comment: 4.0.1 is quite old. The current version of SQL Developer is 17.4.1